# iterrows() itertuples() mutability in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to ask if the pandas yielded from the below iterrows() / itertuples() functions are mutable or not?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

def test():
    for row in df.itertuples(): 
        yield row

a = next(test())
a[0] = 1
```

In this case, will the `df` be mutated?

Comment: No!  `row` is a `namedtuple` from the `collections` library.  It is a subclass of `tuple` and is therefore not mutable.

Comment: Even if it was mutable, it would mutate a copy.

Comment: @ayhan 
So as long as the element in the tuple yielded from .itertuples() are strings or some numbers (int / float), I should be confident that any variable that further reference the element of the tuple should not affect the original df? What if the element in the tuple is a reference, say, another df within that tuple yielded?

Comment: @user7786493 First, like piRSquared said, `a[0] = 1`  would raise an error. You cannot do an assignment. If the content in that row is a mutable object, like a list, `a[0].append(3)`  would change the original DataFrame. But that's only possible by methods like append.

Comment: @ayhan So in this case, does it mean that if a[0] of a tuple is an is an integer (or numpy.float64 in the above example referenced by df), mutability is not relevant here?

Comment: @user7786493 If you are trying to change `a[0]`  through an assignment, yes; it is not relevant.